# Pass a variable into CURSOR's SELECT Query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, cursor

I'm trying the stored procedure below. However, when i pass the actual column name in 'DECLARE cur1' line, the SP returns correct value but when I pass variable name i.e. input parameter (colName), it returns 0. I've added comments in my code below. Is the code correct?

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS test1.checkHardcodedField;
CREATE PROCEDURE test1.checkHardcodedField(IN textValue CHAR(10), colName CHAR(10), OUT counter VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE temp CHAR(16);
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  -- Issue with this statement, returns incorrect value.
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT colName FROM data1;   

  -- This statement works. MSH3 is actual column name
  -- DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT MSH3 FROM data1; 

  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  OPEN cur1;

  read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH cur1 INTO temp;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF temp = textValue THEN
      SET i = i + 1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  SET counter = i;

  CLOSE cur1;
END;
```

Comment: Fieldname cannot be taken from a variable. You must use dynamic SQL (prepared statement).

Comment: But there is one unpleasant thing - cursor cannot be declared using prepared statement...

Comment: Whats the solution then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name (..., fieldname VARCHAR, ...)
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (field VARCHAR(10));
    SET @sql := CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp SELECT ', fieldname, ' FROM tablename;');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
    BEGIN
        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT field FROM tmp;
        ...
    END;
    DROP TABLE tmp;
END
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE CURSOR cur1 FOR SELECT fld FROM tmp;

Comment: @SagarSutar Of course - this is a "how to" scheme, not the final solution.

Comment: Yes, I modified as per my code but its still throwing an error at that line

Comment: Yes. Cursor name (`cur1`) must be specified before `CURSOR` keyword - look at your own code.

Comment: I did that too... still the same error. But i observed one thing, the moment I remove the code from line 4 to line 8, the error disappears.

Comment: @SagarSutar Wrap the codeblock into BEGIN..END - DECLARE must be at the start of a block: *DECLARE is permitted only inside a BEGIN ... END compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.* - [DECLARE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html). Edited.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That worked and I was able to save the stored procedure successfully. But when I call the stored procedure, only this query ('SELECT ', fieldname, ' FROM tablename;') gets executed. Looks like temporary table is getting created but its empty. Hence when the line (DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT field FROM tmp;) gets executed, it has empty column 'field'

Comment: It worked. I've updated the line 4 with INSERT query and it copied the data to tmp table. Thanks a TON buddy!!!

Comment: @SagarSutar If `tmp` table is compact enough (not huge data array), then edit to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (field VARCHAR(10)) ENGINE = Memory;` - this will improve the performance.